# Group adjacent tuple elements matching a predicate into sub-tuples

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, metaprogramming

Given a tuple of some elements and a predicate, how can I group adjacent elements that match the predicate into a sub-tuple?

An example:

```
#include <tuple>

auto is_float = [](auto x) {
    return std::is_same<decltype(x), float>{};
};

int main() {

    auto tup = std::tuple{1.f, 2.f, 3, 4, 5.f, 6.f, 7};
    auto result = magic_foo(is_float, tup); 
    // all adjacent floats are grouped into sub-tuples like this:
    auto expected = std::tuple{std::tuple{1.f, 2.f}, 3, 4, std::tuple{5.f, 6.f}, 7};
    assert(tup == expected);

}
```

Comment: Would the predicate only be dependent on types?

Comment: Yeah, only on types, or more precisely on some  type traits of the types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very crude implementation:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... T1, typename ... T2, std::size_t ... I1, std::size_t ... I2>
auto concat_tuple(const std::tuple<T1...>& t1, const std::tuple<T2...>& t2, std::index_sequence<I1...>, std::index_sequence<I2...>) {
    return std::tuple<T1..., T2...>(
        std::get<I1>(t1)...,
        std::get<I2>(t2)...
    );
}

template <typename ... T1, typename ... T2>
auto concat_tuple(const std::tuple<T1...>& t1, const std::tuple<T2...>& t2) {
    return concat_tuple(t1, t2, 
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T1)>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T2)>{}
    );
}

template <typename ... T, std::size_t ... I>
auto tuple_rest(const std::tuple<T...>& tup, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<I+1>(tup)...);
}

template <typename ... T>
auto tuple_rest(const std::tuple<T...>& tup) {
    return tuple_rest(tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T) - 1>{});
}

template <template <typename T> class Pred, typename ... TAcc>
auto group_by_pred(std::tuple<TAcc...> acc, std::tuple<> tup) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(TAcc) == 0u) {
        return std::make_tuple();
    }
    else return std::make_tuple(acc);
}

template <template <typename T> class Pred, typename ... TAcc, typename T0, typename ... T>
auto group_by_pred(std::tuple<TAcc...> acc, std::tuple<T0, T...> tup) {
    if constexpr (Pred<T0>::value) {
        return group_by_pred<Pred>(
            concat_tuple(acc, std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tup))),
            tuple_rest(tup)
        );
    }
    else {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(TAcc) == 0u) {
            return concat_tuple(
                std::make_tuple(), 
                concat_tuple(
                    std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tup)), 
                    group_by_pred<Pred>(std::make_tuple(), tuple_rest(tup))
                )
            );
        }
        else return concat_tuple(
            std::make_tuple(acc), 
            concat_tuple(
                std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tup)), 
                group_by_pred<Pred>(std::make_tuple(), tuple_rest(tup))
            )
        );
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct not_int : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct not_int<int> : std::false_type {};

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0, 3.0, 2, 3.0);
    auto result = group_by_pred<not_int>(std::make_tuple(), tup);
    std::cout << typeid(result).name() << "\n";
}
```

The idea is simple, but there's a lot of template boilerplate.

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAVlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEABYAHKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiAudSAB1QKhOq0eoYm5lb%2BgWp09o4uRu6e3orKmKrBDATMxAShxqaWqSoxtFk5BHHObh5ePgrZufnhRQ0VVQlJdQCUiqgGxMgcAORSAMwOyIZYANTiYzoEAJ6%2BmAD6BMTMhArz2OIADACC45PTmHMLBAa%2B7HuHJ5ITtFMGs/OLK5gONPfHpy9zpcdOoGsRMMwjH8TsdmAYiDM8Ao1lRWKhmARLgARObcWTcLEQOEIgAe3TmAHZZMcZrSZuDrsRaDMGugQCAkWsFJDMB8sFNlqsIGTSDNUeiCPcqeIKVj5tSTrL5Q8HgRMEZbhiLh9BVoeTMAHRGmYAFR8M11tH1RoNpskotZ7MCAC91pibTMAJLmx0gF1uw3Gz2SaHE1AzNAvDEbG7sCCRhosghskDXW68hZmm33SQANgt5oTmN9abumck2bG%2BzzFvtSZTDiwJK5mAAjgYtEMPt7K9gHcn2Y3MM2lO3OxmdMHe%2BSZQq6fTMIzmSXYxOs0bRSaK0a9hAHvP577gIvu5xdwRON0baR9wfaUeTwtg%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%2BrW2tNNGTb1R6Dkt7W/N1/ZQYRCGoZhuGEcwdAkf6lHMzRjH5Zx32dBNG3TQxgnZyy4nSfC8nKYgL7PZwg49nZAA3NgO05rL5x55kXZuN34e%2Bj4k/QXdc7vWPkNlzAiWxvmZbY4qPlTiqRu6Xoq7vLrZp6kae5mIX5yV4XaXF7UxvHg8Y6LYcE4MrbGexeYcXZnPxuryXmLoWu2KH7fpc0tjejmLft7pFiUIPi/L4PY%2BBbjVuFnb7BKt8LuuLv%2B%2B6UL6HYYl2Tgscuu5H51wgGfPuc0qpfh/tvOBM8EHfiQSLcy29J47xrqxQqh86TgLYvLM%2BeDaTXwgSQh%2Bal%2BYQJfjoN%2BH8v7n1Qfff%2BxcPYVxAaXCqBDCpQNXDNGBn9EG/2HkPEeaCzpjwaoBO6zlTaPWhGCAwqgZi0FQChBwmIQC5U2B2DYXxMpKjGNZf86trqKN0SotRGj6AfE0c9bRvoqBsCUPo1YhiWYmKOJomYfEHCQMJjPMMU1sRNxPoVc0FYw5jANGHOsMSDjiNpMEkKBhWCYjXuDSGRdAHsI%2BNYrStjuFUObrwyCVUUGHjUmgeEwIPgWi%2BHgL2qT0lXm1gEj49SpAhm4DoWg3SUE2WGL0VgIBhjcGGKQUwwwDiTNQGMvGMg5Asn6IMbUTxOCTIIGM2ZX9%2BIgG4DEsY3AACcJyzC5gpBSMYnBJAHDMGMIQYyzCTOmbM0g8zhiTIUCAG22yZnDNIHAWASA0AajwOwMgFB0LgshSAYACgrS%2BAUAgdRpAqAQrVMQH5EBXA7Mma4BwOQlhjM2aQMF0F6AAHlaCsBJQC0gWA%2BKiHYPixleBwQZHTrNNlw50jwhGGSzRyg2WsDwK4LYxAlh6CwKSrZxA8BGDlb0Gg9AmBsA4JwMw/BBDCFECgOQcghDip%2BbAbWIAqBGAIKQblnhhi5k4Ls3oqBfClB%2BcMHarI14SCWTISQzAZg7SpWMb5aQMgaAgDYZopgfA2A6DUTwPgohBDoNGwQybSjxsSLUeoYbSjlCaPoAogglAlEyI0SoDhqjZsTYoCtab6gVqzV0S8fQBhDC4CMsZEyplss%2BSSCwuYdq5jMODIGVNdG0H4uSCAuBCAkDmBs0UehYUeEXTc8kizZAyC2fivZ5hcwGhHQcA4hzJB5gsBSE53AKRPOGC80gSrHU2zeXMsZ3zfmkH%2BU6u9khJlPpPb2hlnzd0Aq/rawIGgzBAA%3D%3D)

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! A few comments: 1) you can use std::tuple_cat to reduce biolerplate, 2) unfortunately MSVC doesn't like it (https://godbolt.org/z/fVmw4a), but you can replace the `std::tuple<TAcc...>` by `TAcc` and use `std::tuple_size` instead of the `sizeof...`, then it works (see here https://godbolt.org/z/NvQZB8 . 3) Unfortunately, msvc will generate very inefficient code in contrast to gcc or clang. Any ideas how to improve that?